# yield с буфером

Tags: c#, .net

Допустим, из итератора извлекается что-то тяжелое или времязатратное.

Можно ли сделать так, что бы итератор хранил некий буфер, что бы вызывающий код не ждал очередного извлечения, а сам буфер пополнялся, пока вызывающий код обрабатывает извлеченный элемент?

Есть идея это делать в отдельной задаче, но правильно ли это?

Comment: почему нет? вполне себе можно использовать какую-нибудь blocking collection по которой бежать в foreach, внутри которого делать yield, а саму коллекцию заполнять в другом потоке, например

Comment: Тут возникает стандартный вопрос - а нужны ли остальные элементы? Я может `FirstOrDefault` запросил. Имхо, тут ещё стоит заморочиться тем, сколько элементов наперед будут высчитываться.

Comment: @Monk, а итератор не может заранее узнать, что было запрошено?

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну смотрите по интерфейсу - по моему ему это делать нечем.